# Is there anywhere online an AI in the mode of "text completion" besides the OpenAI playground?

Tags: gpt, text-generation

By "Text completion" mode I mean that you can input there a full conversation as one single text and the AI thinks that the text you pasted is the past conversation, not a single message.
This way one can start conversation from the middle, and the AI assumes the role. For instance, if in the text above the conversation shows that he tried to agitate you for communism, it will continue doing it further.

It was possible in the text-davinci-003 mode in OpenAI playground.